# I fetched the product names from first table

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-3

I fetched the product names  from first table. and i want to show which company has this product when i clicked the product names . Show those company list form table 2 in Codeigniter. I don't know how to do this, any suggestion regarding this will also be appreciate me. Or this is possible or not in codeigniter ? The way i am doing is right or wrong?

**Controller**

Here i am getting product names from database

```
function index() {
            $data['items_data'] = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_name();
            $this->load->view('include/header');
            $this->load->view('visa/visa',$data);
            $this->load->view('include/footer');
        }
```

[image: Here i am getting product names from database]
Here i am trying to do when user click to product name . in the next page only show the company lists which company contain that product.

**Models**

```
function get_items_name() {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $query = $this->get_table1();
            return $query->result();

        }

function get_items_company_list($id) {
            $query = $this->db->query('select company_details.company_name, company_details.address, company_details.contact_number from tbl_product right join company_details on tbl_product.item_id = company_details.item_id where tbl_product.item_id = "$id"');

            return  $query->result();
        }
```

**views**
Here i am showing the product names

```
<?php
             $data = "";
             foreach($items_data as $row){

                    $data .=  '<li class="list-group-item">
                                <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right" style=""><p class="pull-left">'.$row->item_id.'</p></span>
                                <a href="'.base_url("Hotels/visa_dashboard").'">'.$row->item_name.'<span class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right" style=""></span>        
                                </a>
                            </li>';

                } 
                echo $data;
                ?>
```

In the next page how can i get company lists.

```
   <?php


foreach($items_company_data as $row) {
                      echo $row->company_name;
                      echo $row->contact_number;
                      echo $row->address;

            }

              ?>
```

Comment: can you show us your method `get_table1()`

Comment: ****            `function get_table1() {
   $table = $this->db->get("tbl_product");
   return $table;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to display the company list in this URL Hotels/visa_dashboard, then you need to pass the item id as query string or add this as parameter in your method.

Example in Views

```
<?php
             $data = "";
             foreach($items_data as $row){

                    $data .=  '<li class="list-group-item">
                                <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right" style=""><p class="pull-left">'.$row->item_id.'</p></span>
                                <a href="'.base_url("Hotels/visa_dashboard/".$row->item_id).'">'.$row->item_name.'<span class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right" style=""></span>        
                                </a>
                            </li>';

                } 
                echo $data;
                ?>
```

And in your function

```
public function visa_dashboard($item_id){

//get the query
$result = $yourmodel->get_items_company_list($item_id);

$data['company_list'] = $result;

$this->load->view(YOUR_TEMPLATE/company_view.php,$data);
}
```

And in the company_view.php

```
foreach($items_company_data as $row) {
                      echo $row->company_name;
                      echo $row->contact_number;
                      echo $row->address;

            }
```